# A guess about sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $a_n \le b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ . Can we conclude $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$ ? Intuitively , it seems right but I can't prove it or find a counterexample .

Comment: How do you intuively see this as right? When you start explaining your intuitive thoughts about this problem in words you will automatically find a rigorous proof. Most simple proofs are intuitive and obvious, it is only a matter of putting your thoughts into words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

To see how, start with the definition: we say that $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ if given any $M\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $a_n\geq M$ for $n$ sufficiently large.  (That is: for any $M$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $a_n\geq M$.)

Clearly, though, this implies that for $n\geq N$, $b_n\geq a_n\geq M$; therefore $b_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if this result also holds if we weaken the assumption that $a_n\leq b_n$ only holds *eventually*, i.e. that we have $a_n\leq b_n$ only for $n\geq N$, where $N\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Limits as $n\to\infty$ only care about eventual behavior, so yes. You just need to choose $N$ large enough so both properties hold.

Answer (score 2):

Given $M>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies that 
$$
M\leq a_n\leq b_n
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

(If I didn't read the question wrong...) the proof should be a simple application of the definition of limits.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$$
means that for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $n_{a} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k \geq n_{a}$, $a_{k} \geq N$.

To show that the sequence $B = \{b_1, b_2, ...\}$ tends to infinity, given an $N$, we need to find a $n_{b}$ such that $\forall k \geq n_b$, $b_{k} \geq N$. Since $a_i \leq b_i$, our choice of $n_b$ is simply $n_a$. Then $\forall k \geq n_{a}$, $b_k \geq a_k \geq N$ as required.