# Limit of the difference between two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, information-theory

Suppose that $l_1, l_2,\dots$ are natural numbers such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}2^{-l_i}\le1 \tag{1}$$ and let $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i - \log_2n \tag{2}$$ I think $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ doesn't exist but I'm not sure about that. For example for $l_i = i$ we have: $$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}2^{-i} = \frac{1/2}{1-1/2} = 1 \\ a_n = \frac{1}{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \log_2{n} = \frac{n+1}{2} - \log_2{n}$$ It can be shown that in this case $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$. Is it possible to find a sequence of natural numbers $\{l_i\}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists?

**Attempt:** We can rewrite $a_n$ as follows: $$a_n = \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i - n\log_2n) = \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log_2n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(l_i - \log_2n)$$ It seems that condition $(1)$ imposes some constraint on the growth of $l_i - \log_2n$ for large $n$. If we can compare this growth with $n$, it would be possible to find the limit.

**Background:** This question comes from information theory. A prefix-free code satisfies Kraft inequality which is $(1)$. For a source with uniform distribution on $n$ symbols the entropy is $\log_2n$. Also the average length of code for this source is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_il_i = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i$$ So the redundancy in code can be computed as $(2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b_k = 2^{-l_k}$, or $l_k = -\log_2 b_k$. Then

$$ \begin{align}
a_n&=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \log_2 b_k  - \log_2 n \tag{1}\\
&=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(k \,b_k) +\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log_2 k - \log_2 n \tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2 \frac{1}{k \,b_k} +O(1) \tag{3}\\
&\ge  \log_2 \frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k b_k} +O(1) \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

where in $(2)\to (3)$ we've used $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(k) = \log_2 (n!) = n \log_2 n - n \log_2 e +O(\log n)$.

And for $(3)\to (4)$ we've used the log-sum inequality.

Let $B = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \le 1$

If $B=1$, then $b_k$ represents a discrete distribution function. In that case we have

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n k \, b_k \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$ (proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4748044/312)). Hence $a_n$ in $(4)$ diverges.

This also (a fortiori) applies for $B<1$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Could you explain why $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2 \frac{1}{k \,b_k}$ diverges?

Comment: The only part that I couldn't understand was $b_k = o(1/k)$. We know $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \le 1$, how does this implies $b_k = o(1/k)$?

Comment: @S.H.W That's false my mistake, I will see if it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. How it can be proved that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, b_k =o(n)$?

Comment: I think there is a problem with $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, b_k =  \frac{1}{n}(B_{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n B_k)$$ For example by plugging $n = 3$ it can be seen that RHS and LHS are different. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k$, then $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, b_k = \frac{1}{n}(nS_n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}S_k)$$

Comment: Also note that the dummy index $k$ inside summation goes from $1$ to $n$ and we're not allowed to assume that $k \gt n_0$.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure about it either. I'd ask the question here, I think it's interesting in its own: 
Prove or disprove that for a discrete pmf over the positive integers $p_k$ we have  $\lim _{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n k\, p_k  = 0$

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting question. I think the main question here is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} nb_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{2^{l_n}}$$ since it's equal to $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}nb_n$$ So we should study the behavior of $b_n$ for large $n$ under the constraints $b_n = 2^{-l_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \le 1$.

Comment: For that purpose I tried to find other $b_n$'s (except $b_n = 2^{-n}$) that satisfies the constraints but I couldn't find any other examples. Do you know any source or procedure for finding the codeword lengths in the infinite case?

Comment: I have written an answer using your ideas. I would be grateful if you would check it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer using @leonbloy's ideas. Let $b_k = 2^{-l_k},\ l_k = -\log_2(b_k)$ and $B = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \le 1$. We can rewrite $a_n$ as follows
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \log_2(b_k)  - \log_2(n) \\
&=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(k \,b_k) +\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log_2(k) - \log_2(n) \\
&=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(k \,b_k) +\frac{1}{n} \log_2(n!) - \log_2(n)\end{align}$$We show that the sequence $$c_n = \frac{1}{n} \log_2(n!) - \log_2(n)$$ is convergent and the sequence $$d_n = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(k \,b_k) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(\frac{1}{k \,b_k})$$ tends to $\infty$, so their sum tends to $\infty$.

**Limit of $c_n$:** Note that $c_n$ can be rearranged as $$c_n = \log_2(\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n})$$Using the [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960335/how-are-the-stirling-based-bounds-for-the-factorial-function-proven) $$e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n<n!<e^{\frac{1}{12n}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ we have $$e^{\frac{1}{12n^2+n}}({2\pi n})^{\frac{1}{2n}}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)<\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}<e^{\frac{1}{12n^2}}({2\pi n})^{\frac{1}{2n}}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right) $$ It's obvious that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{\frac{1}{12n^2+n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{12n^2}} = 1$$ Now we compute the following limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}({2\pi n})^{\frac{1}{2n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp(\frac{\ln(2\pi n)}{2n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} [\exp(\frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2n})][\exp(\frac{\ln(n)}{2n})] = \\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp(\frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2n}) \times \lim_{n \to \infty}\exp(\frac{\ln(n)}{2n}) = \exp(0)\times\exp(0) = 1$$ where we have used of the fact $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n} = 0$$ So by the squeeze theorem we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n} = \frac{1}{e}$$ which implies $$\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \log_2(\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}) = \log_2(\frac{1}{e}) = -\log_2(e)$$
**Limit of $d_n$:** The [log sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_sum_inequality) states that for nonnegative numbers $g_1,\dots,g_n$ and $f_1,\dots,f_n$ we have $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}g_k\log_2({\frac{g_k}{f_k}})\ge(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}g_k)\log_2({\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}g_k}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}f_k}})$$Let $g_k = 1$ and $f_k = kb_k$, then $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\log_2({\frac{1}{kb_k}})\ge(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}1)\log_2({\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}1}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}kb_k}}) \implies d_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(\frac{1}{k \,b_k}) \ge \log_2(\frac{n}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}kb_k})$$ Assuming that $l_1\le l_2 \le \dots$ it can be [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746725/lower-bound-for-a-sequence/) that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} nb_n = 0$$ which implies that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}kb_k = 0 $$ since the limit of a convergent sequence coincides with its [arithmetic mean](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean). This in turn implies that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}kb_k} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}kb_k} = \infty \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \log_2(\frac{n}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}kb_k}) = \infty$$ Finally, since the lower bound on $d_n$ diverges [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608105/a-guess-about-sequences) $$\lim_{n \to \infty} d_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_2(\frac{1}{k \,b_k}) = \infty$$ Note that if the $l_i$'s are not in order, then the limit of $nb_n$ isn't necessarily $0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747008/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-sequence) for some examples) but it can be [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747524/convergence-of-sequence-after-rearranging-a-part-of-it) that out of order lengths can only make $a_n$ larger, so even in that case $a_n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: I think that $\lim_{n \to \infty} nb_n = 0$ is false, see the counterxample I linked. The proof you link to is only for monotonous sequences.

Comment: @leonbloy Yes it works for monotone sequences but we can rearrange the lengths such that $l_1\le l_2 \le \dots$. This rearrangement ensures that $b_n$ is nonincreasing.

Comment: @leonbloy I've edited the answer in order to cover the case where lengths are not in order. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i - \log_2n \tag{2}$$
and *l<sub>i</sub> = i*.

Taken apart the expression becomes $$a_n=(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i) - \log_2n \tag{2}$$

Which becomes $$\frac{1}{n}\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} - \log_2n$$
Which equals $$\frac{(n+1)}{2} - \log_2n$$

I believe the question is whether both parts together would approach a definite point as n approaches infinity:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}$$

$\log_2{n}$ can be replaced with this expression $\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}$ and proved by
$$2^{\log_2{n}} = 2^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}} = (e^{\ln 2})^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}} = e^{\ln n} = n$$

Visually the graph of $\frac{n + 1}{2}$ diverges from the graph of $\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}$ so therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ = $\frac{\infty + 1}{2}$

There is also the option of replacing the logarithmic function of 2 into a power series:

There exists a power series for ln such that 0 ≤ x ≤ 2
$$\ln(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1^i}{i+1}(x - 1)^{i+1}$$$$x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^5}{5}\dots$$

likewise for the domain $\frac{1}{2}$ ≤ x ≤ $\infty$
$$\ln(\frac{1}{x}) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1^i}{i+1}(\frac{1}{x} - 1)^{i+1}$$

multiplying both sides by -1 gives $$-\ln(\frac{1}{x}) = -\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1^i}{i+1}(\frac{1}{x} - 1)^{i+1}$$
becomes
$$-\ln(\frac{1}{x}) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1^{i+1}}{i+1}(\frac{1}{x} - 1)^{i+1}$$

So when $$\lim_{n \to \infty}$$
a<sub>$\infty$</sub> = $\frac{n+1}{2} - \log_{2}{\infty}$
can be restated as
$$a_\infty = \frac{\infty+1}{2} - \frac{\ln{\infty}}{\ln 2}$$

or as $$a_\infty = \frac{\infty+1}{2} - \frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1^{i+1}}{i+1}(\frac{1}{\infty} - 1)^{i+1}$$

which  can be reduced in the following steps

$$a_\infty = \frac{\infty+1}{2} - \frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1^{i+1}}{i+1}(0 - 1)^{i+1}$$
$$a_\infty = \frac{\infty+1}{2} - \frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1^{i+1}}{i+1}(-1)^{i+1}$$
$$a_\infty = \frac{\infty+1}{2} - \frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1^{i+1}}{i+1}$$
$$a_\infty = \frac{\infty+1}{2} - \frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i+1}$$
$$a_\infty = \frac{\infty+1}{2} - \frac{1}{\ln 2} - \frac{1}{2 \ln 2} - \frac{1}{3 \ln 2} - \frac{1}{4 \ln 2}\dots$$

diverging to $\frac{\infty}{2}$

Comment: Note that $l_i = i$ is an example. You should consider all lengths such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 2^{-l_i} \le 1$.

Comment: Also you are treating $\infty$ like a real number which is not correct.

Answer (score -2):

The sequence $a_n$ diverges due to the $\log_{2}(n)$ term. The logarithm grows very slowly, but diverges as n approaches infinity.

Comment: This does not answer the question for the difference.  You can have individual terms diverge but have the difference converge.

Comment: Assuming that we can order $ 1 \leq l_{1} \leq l_{2} \cdots $, I rewrote the sum to consider an arbitrary sequence where the $l_{i}$ terms are allowed to be repeated. Now that you mention it, I shouldn't assume that the series will "diverge" faster than the logarithm term.