# Lower bound for a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Following my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745427/limit-of-the-difference-between-two-sequences), suppose that $l_1\le l_2\le \dots $ are natural numbers such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}2^{-l_i}\le1$$I want to find a lower bound on $l_i$ in order to compute the limit $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n}{2^{l_n}}$$ which I guess is zero but not sure about that. I think $l_i\ge i$ is a possible lower bound since $$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}2^{-i}=1$$ but I don't know how to show $l_i \ge i$ for all possible choices of $l_i$.

**Edit:** Here's a [follow-up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747008/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-sequence) to this question.

Comment: Let $l_1=l_2=l_3=2$ and $l_i=i$ for $i\ge 4.$ Then $l_3<3.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks, you're right and my guess was wrong. Do you know any lower bound on $l_i$ which permits us to compute the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is barely more general to prove (mainly because $x\mapsto2^{-x}$ is a decreasing bijection) that for any nonincreasing map $f:\mathbb N^*\to\mathbb R_+$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f(i)<+\infty\implies nf(n)\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.
$$

Once the statement above is proved, just apply it to $f$ such that $f(i)=2^{-l_i}$.

Before proving it, I would like to convince you that it is actually a trivial fact when you interpret it geometrically. Indeed, plot $f$ on a graph, then $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f(i)<+\infty$ can be seen as the area $\mathcal A$ between $0$ and the graph of $f$, and $nf(n)$ can be seen as the area of the rectangle $[0,n]\times[0,f(n)]$. The area of this rectangle is of course smaller than fraction of $\mathcal A$ consisting of everything below $f(n)$. As $f(n)$ vanishes as $n$ goes to $+\infty$, the latter area, and therefore $nf(n)$, vanishes as well.

Now I propose two proofs which are actually none other than two ways of writing the geometric ideas above.

### Proof 1

$$
nf(n)=\sum_{i=1}^nf(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\min(f(i),f(n))\le\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\min(f(i),f(n)).
$$

We have that $\min(f(i),f(n))\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ and $\min(f(i),f(n))\le f(i)$, so by the dominated convergence theorem (discrete version, applied with series), $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\min(f(i),f(n))\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$, which proves the statement.

### Proof 2

Using Fubini's theorem for series with nonnegative terms,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f(i)=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=i}^{+\infty}(f(k)-f(k+1))=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{i=1}^k(f(k)-f(k+1))=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k(f(k)-f(k+1)),
$$
hence $\displaystyle\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}k(f(k)-f(k+1))\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ as the remainder of a convergent series. Then we conclude with
$$
nf(n)=n\sum_{i=n}^{+\infty}(f(i)-f(i+1))=\sum_{i=n}^{+\infty}n(f(i)-f(i+1))\le\sum_{i=n}^{+\infty}i(f(i)-f(i+1))\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the case that $f(n)$ is not monotone and $f(n) = 2^{-l_n}$ where $l_n \in \mathbb{N}$, is it possible to prove that $\lim_{n}nf(n)=0$? I found some counterexamples but none of them satisfies the condition $f(n) = 2^{-l_n}$, they are merely non-monotonic sequences.

Comment: I've made that to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747008/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-sequence). I would be grateful if you would check it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $l_i\in {\mathbb N}$ be nondecreasing. Since $\sum 2^{-l_i}$ is bounded, one has $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} l_i=\infty.$ One needs to prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac n{2^{l_n}}=0.\qquad (1)$$ One can prove a more general result:

**Proposition**. Let $a_n>0$ be a nondecreasing sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {a_n}$ converges. Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac n{a_n}=0.$$

*Proof*. For every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $N_1\in {\mathbb N}$ such that $\sum_{n>N_1}\frac 1{a_n}<\frac{\epsilon}2.$ Choose $N\geq N_1$ such that $\frac {N_1}{a_N}<\frac {\epsilon}2,$ hence $\frac {N_1}{a_n}<\frac {\epsilon}2$ for $n\geq N.$

Then if $n>N,$ one has $$\frac n{a_n}=\frac {N_1}{a_n}+\frac{n-N_1}{a_n}<\frac{\epsilon}2+\sum_{i=N_1+1}^n\frac 1 {a_i}$$
$$<\frac{\epsilon}2+\sum_{i>N_1}\frac 1 {a_i}<\frac {\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2=\epsilon.$$ This proves the proposition.

Now (1) follows by letting $a_n=2^{l_n}.$

Comment: Thanks. Would you explain why we have "For every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n>N_1}\frac 1{a_n}<\frac{\epsilon}2$"?

Comment: @S.H.W That follows by definition since $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges.

Comment: Here's a [follow-up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747008/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-sequence) to this question. I would be grateful if you would check it.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning $na_n\to 0,$ when $a_n$ is a nonincreasing nonnegative and summable sequence, my favorite proof is as follows. $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k\ge \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k\ge na_{2n}\ge na_{2n+1}$$ Hence $$\lim_n2na_{2n}=0\quad \lim_n(2n+1)a_{2n+1}=0$$ Thus $$\lim_nna_n=0$$

Comment: In the case that $a_n$ is not monotone and $a_n = 2^{-l_n}$ where $l_n \in \mathbb{N}$, is it possible to prove that $\lim_nna_n=0$? I found some counterexamples but none of them satisfies the condition $a_n = 2^{-l_n}$, they are merely non-monotonic sequences.

Comment: I've made that to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747008/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-sequence). I would be grateful if you would check it.

Comment: That's clearly the best answer