# Asymptotic behavior of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I'm trying to generalize my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746725/lower-bound-for-a-sequence/). Suppose that function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following conditions:

$1. \ \ \forall i\in \mathbb{N}:f(i) = 2^{-l_i} \text{ for some} \ l_i\in \mathbb{N} \\ 2. \ \ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(i)\le1$

I want to find the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}nf(n) = \ ?$$In the case that the first condition is ignored and $f(i)$ is not monotone, we can construct $f(i)$ such that the limit doesn't exist. Is it possible to construct such an example for the case both conditions are satisfied? Also if the function is monotone, the limit is zero. It can be easily shown that:

$1. \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}:\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i) \lt 1 \\ 2. \ \forall i\in \mathbb{N}: \ f(i)\le \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It won't be hard to construct a counterexample even when both conditions are satisfied, because those conditions don't care about the order of the values $f(i)$ but the limit conclusion does. Letting the values $f(i)$ be all negative powers of $2$ once each satisfies the first two conditions; I recommend looking for an ordering of those values that violates the limit conclusion.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks. Yes that was my intuition too but I couldn't find any ordering for which the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}nf(n)$$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Hint: force $nf(n) = \sqrt n$ infinitely often.

Comment: @GregMartin Using your hint, if we define $$f(n) = n^{-1/2}=(2\times4^k)^{-1} \ \ \ \text{if} \ n =( 2\times 4^k)^2$$ then we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2i-1}} = \frac{2}{3}$$ so we should define the other terms such that their sum is at most $1/3$. How this can be done?

Comment: @S.H.W I think you meant if $n=(4^k/2)^2=(2^{2k-1})^2$ then define $f(n)=(4^k/2)^{-1}=1/2^{2k-1}.$ Let $A:=\{(2^{2k-1})^2~|~k\in {\mathbb N}\}.$ Then $$\sum_{n\in A}f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^{2i-1}}=\frac 2 3.$$

Comment: For $n\in {\mathbb N}\setminus A,$ one may define $f(n)=2^{-2n}.$ Then $$\sum_{n\in {\mathbb N}\setminus A} f(n)=\sum_{n\in {\mathbb N}\setminus A}\frac 1 {4^n}<\sum_{n\in{\mathbb N}}\frac 1{4^n}=\frac 1 3.$$

Comment: @Pythagoras Thanks. I was considering $k = 0,1,\dots$ instead of $k = 1,2,\dots$. I think that your example provides a counterexample for my question. If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example** 1. (Using the ideas of Greg Martin and S.H.W.)

Let $A=\{(2\times 4^k)^2~|~k\in \{0\}\cup {\mathbb N}\}.$ Define $f:A\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ by $$f(n)=n^{-1/2},~{\rm so~}f((2\times 4^{i-1})^2)=\frac 1{2^{2i-1}},i\in {\mathbb N}.$$ Then $$\sum_{n\in A}f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^{2i-1}}=\frac 2 3$$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nf(n)=\sqrt{n}\rightarrow \infty$ if $n$ stays in $A.$

To extend the above $f$ to a function $f:{\mathbb N}\rightarrow {\mathbb R},$ let $f(n)=2^{-2n}$ for $n\in {\mathbb N}\setminus A.$ And one checks that $$\sum_{n\in {\mathbb N}\setminus A}f(n)=\sum_{n\in {\mathbb N}\setminus A}2^{-2n} < \sum_{n\in {\mathbb N}}2^{-2n}=\frac 1 3, $$ hence $f$ satisfies the two conditions in the original question but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} nf(n)$ does not exist.

**Example** 2. Let $f:{\mathbb N}\rightarrow A:=\{2^{-i}~|~i\in {\mathbb N}\}$ be a bijection defined by $$f(i)=2^{-i},i\in {\mathbb N}.$$ Then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)=1.$ This function satisfies the two conditions in the original question with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nf(n)=0.$ One can do a “surgery” of $f$ to get a bijection $f^*:{\mathbb N}\rightarrow A$ satisfying the two conditions but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nf^*(n)$ does not exist. To do this, let $$B:=\{2^{2k-1}~|~k\in {\mathbb N}\}~{\rm and~}C:=\{2^{-2k}~|~k\in {\mathbb N}\}$$ and define $$f^*:B\rightarrow C$$ by $$f^*(2^{2k-1})=2^{-2k},k\in {\mathbb N}.$$ Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} nf^*(n)=\frac 1 2~{\rm if~}n\in B.\qquad (1)$$ To get an extension for $f^*$ to $f^*:{\mathbb N}\rightarrow A,$ one just defines a natural map $$f^*:{\mathbb N}\setminus B\rightarrow A\setminus C$$ such that ${\mathbb N}\setminus B$ and $A\setminus C$ retain the natural ordering, and $f^*$ maps the $j$th element of ${\mathbb N}\setminus B$ to the $j$th element of $A\setminus C.$ Then $f^*:{\mathbb N}\rightarrow A$ will be as follows if one lists the first few terms, where $2,8,32,$ etc. are elements in $B$.

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
i & 1 &{\bf 2}& 3& 4& \cdots& 7& {\bf 8}& 9&\cdots& 23& \cdots&{\bf 32}\\ 
\hline 
f^*(i) & 2^{-1} & 2^{-2}& 2^{-3}& 2^{-5}& \cdots& 2^{-11}& 2^{-4}
& 2^{-13}& \cdots& 2^{-41}& \cdots& 2^{-6}\\
\hline  
\end{array}$$

By construction, $\sum_i f^*(i)=\sum_if(i)=1$ and $f^*(i)=2^{-l_i}$ for some $l_i\in {\mathbb N}.$ Now one can find a subsequence of ${\mathbb N}$ consisting of prime numbers $p$ such that $$2^{2k-1}<p<2^{2k+1},$$ the existence of which is guaranteed by the Bertrand’s postulate. One can show that $$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}pf^*(p)=0.\qquad (2)$$

To see this, suppose $p$ (indexed by $k$) with $2^{2k-1}<p<2^{2k+1}$ has been chosen. Then one has $$f^*(p)=2^{-[2(p-k)-1]},$$ since $f^*(p)$ has to avoid $k$ terms in $C$ (corresponding to the $k$ terms in $B$ as pre-images, namely $2^1,2^3,\cdots,2^{2k-1}$ on which $f^*$ is defined) with other $p-k$ terms in $A\setminus C=\{2^{-(2i-1)}~|~i\in {\mathbb N}\}$ filled.

It follows that $$pf^*(p)=\frac p{2^{2p-2k-1}}=\frac p{2^{2p}}\cdot 2^{2k+1}<\frac {(2^{2k+1})^2}{2^{2p}}=\frac {(2^2\cdot 2^{2k-1})^2}{2^{2p}}<\frac {2^4\cdot p^2}{2^{2p}}\rightarrow 0$$ as $p\rightarrow \infty.$ This proves (2). Combining (1) and (2), one sees that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nf^*(n)$ does not exist.

**Note**. There is much freedom to choose $p.$ For example, one can choose $p_1=7$ with $2^{2\cdot 1-1}<7<2^{2\cdot 2-1}$ and $p_2=23$ with $2^{2\cdot 2-1}<23<2^{2\cdot 3-1},$ so from the table, one sees that $f^*(7)=2^{-[2(7-1)-1]}=2^{-11}$ and $f^*(23)=2^{-[2(23-2)-1]}=2^{-41},$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I've asked a separate [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747524/rearranging-a-part-of-sequence) which is related to the original question. It would be great if you would check it.