# Convergence of sequence after rearranging a part of it

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4746928/325808$$) I've shown that if we assume $l_1\le l_2 \le \dots$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-l_i}\le 1$ then $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i - \log_2n$$ tends to $\infty$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. What can be said about the convergence of $a_n$ if we reorder lengths $l_i$? I think $a_n$ still goes to $\infty$ but I don't know whether it's true or not. Note that the mentioned proof doesn't work without the assumption of $l_1\le l_2 \le \dots$.

Comment: Reordering can only make each $a_n$ larger

Comment: @CJDowd Would you elaborate more on it? It would be nice if you could write a proof.

Comment: This question statement misses the crucial fact $\sum \log_2 l_i \le 1$

Comment: @leonbloy Why do you think that assumption is crucial here? I think the CJ Dowd's answer shows that's not necessary.

Comment: This makes no sense. Simple counterxample: let $l_i = c$ (constant). Then, $a_n \to -\infty$

Comment: @leonbloy The answer shows that $a'_n \geq a_n$, in that case $a'_n = a_n$ holds.

Comment: Forget about the reordering. I'm saying that your original assertion is false. $a_n$ does not tend to $\infty$

Comment: @leonbloy You're right about that, I will change the question but the main conclusion here is that reordering only makes the sequence larger and this fact doesn't depend on $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-l_i}\le 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $l_i'$ be any reordering of the sequence of lengths, and $a'_n$ the corresponding new corresponding value. For a given $n$, let $l'_{i_1} \leq \dots \leq l'_{i_n}$ be the reordering of $l'_1, \dots, l'_n$ into size order. Then
$$a_n' = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n l'_i - \log_2 n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n l'_{i_j} - \log_2 n.$$

However, since the original $l_j$ are in order to start with, we conclude that $l'_{i_j} \geq l_j$, so that
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1} l'_{i_j} - \log_2 n \geq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1} l_{j} - \log_2 n = a_n.$$

Hence $a'_n \geq a_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice proof.

Comment: I just don't get it why we conclude that $l'_{i_j} \geq l_j$

Comment: @leonbloy Because by assumption $\{l_j\}$ were in order. I think following example makes the proof clear. Take $l_i = i$: $$\{l_i\} = 1,2,3,4,5,\dots$$ Apply some rearrangement: $$\{l_i'\} = 100,4,25,3,90,\dots$$ For each $n$ we take the first $n$ numbers and reorder them: $$n=1: \{l_{i_j}'\} = 100 \\ n=2: \{l_{i_j}'\} = 4,100 \\ n=3: \{l_{i_j}'\} = 4,25,100  \\ n=4: \{l_{i_j}'\} = 3,4,25,100 \\ n=5: \{l_{i_j}'\} = 3,4,25,90,100 \\ \dots$$