# Divergence of mean for discrete distributions

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Let $p_k \ge 0 $ be a probability distribution over the positive integers: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k = 1$

Let $ \mu_n = \sum_{k=1}^n  k \, p_k$, so that $\mu_{\infty}=\mu$  is its mean - it the limit exists.

We know that $\mu_n$ does not necessarily converge, there are discrete distributions with infinite mean. For example, for $p_k = \frac1{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$, we have $\mu_n= \log n + O(1)$

My question is : what can we say about the asymptotics of $\mu_n$ in general?

In particular, can this be proven or disproven? $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{1}{n} \mu_n =0$$

Comment: Is the second $=$ in the definition of $\mu_n$ a typo?

Comment: Yes, fixed, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this limit is $0$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k$ is convergent there is some $n_0$ such that $\sum_{k=n_0+1}^\infty p_k < \varepsilon/2$. For $n>n_0$ we have
$$
0 \le \frac{1}{n}\mu_n= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} kp_k + \sum_{k=n_0+1}^{n} \frac{k}{n}p_k \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} kp_k  + \sum_{k=n_0+1}^n p_k
\le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} kp_k  + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
Now choose $n_1 > n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} kp_k < \varepsilon/2$. For $n\ge n_1$ we get:
$$
0 \le  \frac{1}{n}\mu_n \le \frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} kp_k + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: Thanks. This amounts to $\mu_n = o(n)$. I wonder if this is the tightest asymptotics?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think $\mu_n=o(n)$ is quite tight. Maybe testing $p_k=1/k^\alpha-1/(k+1)^\alpha$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ could bring some clarity. But I don't know how complicated the calculations will be.